# Can someone help me understanding reference frames in OxTS data in KITTI Vision Benchmark dataset?

Tags: kinematics, kalman-filter, imu

If anyone has worked with KITTI dataset, can you explain the reference frame used in roll pitch yaw values?

I downloaded the raw data from this link:
http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php

The KITTI data states the following:

roll:  roll angle (rad),    0 = level, positive = left side up,      range: -pi   .. +pi

pitch: pitch angle (rad),   0 = level, positive = front down,        range: -pi/2 .. +pi/2

yaw:   heading (rad),       0 = east,  positive = counter clockwise, range: -pi   .. +pi

**By counter clockwise do they mean car turning left is positive yaw?**

Also what is the convention for positive and negative for the angular rates?

wx:    angular rate around x (rad/s)

wy:    angular rate around y (rad/s)

wz:    angular rate around z (rad/s)

I would assume that x y and z are forward leftward and upward as mentioned in the text.